# After changing tabpage, the combobox crashes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, tabcontrol

I have a combobox outside my tabcontrol. In each tab control there is a datagridview full of values. In the combobox you can choose a conversion for all values. For example eV→meV.
When i am in the first tab and use the combobox there are no problems, but after i switch the tab and then wanna use the combobox the program list down however the whole combobox is full of `try/catch`

```
private void OpenB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string[] result = new string[2];
        bool lesen = false;
        int Spalte = 0;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            //Datagridview will be rested, so all values and rows are removed

            for (int i = 1; i < Anzahl; i++)
            {
                DGV[i].Rows.Clear();
            }

            Anzahl = openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length;
            counter = new int[Anzahl];

            try
            {
                if (tabControl1.TabCount < Anzahl)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= Anzahl; i++)
                    {
                        if (i > tabControl1.TabCount)
                        {
                            string title = "Tab " + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
                            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);
                            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

                            DataGridView NewDGV = new DataGridView();

                            NewDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
                            NewDGV.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
                            NewDGV.Columns.Add("Energy", "Energy");
                            NewDGV.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
                            NewDGV.Columns.Add("Count Rate", "Count Rate");
                            NewDGV.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
                            NewDGV.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
                            NewDGV.Name = "NewDGV" + Convert.ToString(i);
                            NewDGV.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                            NewDGV.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 379);
                            NewDGV.TabIndex = i;
                            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in NewDGV.Columns)
                                col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
                            NewDGV.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;

                            DGV.Add(NewDGV);

                            tabControl1.TabPages[i - 1].Controls.Add(NewDGV);

                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (tabControl1.TabCount > Anzahl)
                {
                    for (int i = tabControl1.TabCount - 1; i >= Anzahl; i--)
                    {
                        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.TabPages[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }

            try
            {
                //Double arrays and Datagridview will be attuned to the count of data
                eV = new double[openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length][];
                meV = new double[openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length][];
                cm = new double[openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length][];
                CR = new double[openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length][];
                CRmax = new double[openFileDialog1.FileNames.Length][];


                for (int i = 0; i < Anzahl; i++)
                {
                    //Naming the columns after data names
                    string[] Dateiname = openFileDialog1.FileNames[i].Split('\\');
                    int L = Dateiname.Length;

                    tabControl1.TabPages[i].Text = Dateiname[L-1];

                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            //Datafiles will be read one by one
            DataRead(result, ref lesen, ref Spalte);
        }
    }

    /// Reading loop
    /// 
    /// double[] eV2 = Energy values of the current data file in eV
    /// double[] meV2 = Energy values of the current data file in meV
    /// double[] cm2 = Energy values of the current data file in cm^-1
    /// double[] CR2 = Intensities of the current data file in CR
    /// double[] CRmax2 = normalizied Intensities of the current data file in 1/CRmax
    private void DataRead(string[] result, ref bool lesen, ref int Spalte)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte < Anzahl; Spalte++)
        {
            string line;

            lesen = false;
            counter[Spalte] = 0;
            try
            {
                Ursprung = openFileDialog1.FileNames[Spalte];
                //initialize stream reader
                System.IO.StreamReader file1 = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileNames[Spalte]);
                //read line per line in stream reader
                while (((line = file1.ReadLine()) != null))
                {
                    counter[Spalte]++;
                    Count2 = counter[Spalte];
                    Count2 = Count2 / 2;

                    try
                    {
                        string[] splitter = line.Split(' ');
                        if ((splitter[0] == "S") && (splitter[1] == "0000"))
                        {
                            lesen = true;
                            counter[Spalte] = 0;
                        }
                        if (lesen == true)
                        {
                            //Rows will be filled an added with data value strings
                            if (counter[Spalte] % 2 == 0)
                            {
                                result[0] = splitter[2];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result[1] = splitter[2];

                                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                                DGV[Spalte].Rows.Add();
                                int Zeile = (counter[Spalte] - 1) / 2;
                                DGV[Spalte][0, Zeile].Value = result[0];
                                DGV[Spalte][1, Zeile].Value = result[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                //Streamreader is closed
                file1.Close();
                counter[Spalte] = counter[Spalte] / 2;

                //Current datagridviw values are saved in arrays
                //The conversions will be calculated and saved in new arrays
                //So every unit gets its own array
                double[] eV2 = new double[counter[Spalte]];
                double[] meV2 = new double[counter[Spalte]];
                double[] cm2 = new double[counter[Spalte]];
                double[] CR2 = new double[counter[Spalte]];
                double[] CRmax2 = new double[counter[Spalte]];


                //Conversion calculation
                for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                {
                    eV2[i] = Convert.ToDouble(DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value);
                    CR2[i] = Convert.ToDouble(DGV[Spalte][1, i].Value);
                    meV2[i] = 1000 * eV2[i];
                    cm2[i] = 8066 * eV2[i];
                }

                //Current file's arrays are saved in double arrays
                eV[Spalte] = eV2;
                CR[Spalte] = CR2;
                meV[Spalte] = meV2;
                cm[Spalte] = cm2;

                for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                {
                    CRmax2[i] = CR2[i] / CR2.Max();
                }

                CRmax[Spalte] = CRmax2;

                //Chosen conversion replaces values in datagridview
                if (Hilfe == 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                    {
                        DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value = meV2[i];
                    }
                }
                else if (Hilfe == 2)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                    {
                        DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value = cm2[i];
                    }
                }

                if (Hilfe2 == 1)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                    {
                        DGV[Spalte][1, i].Value = CRmax2[i];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Es ist ein Fehler beim Einlesen eingetreten");
            }
        }
    }
    /// Energy Unit
    /// Choses between eV, meV, 1/cm
    /// Datagridview values are replaced by the unit array values
    /// Hilfe... Saves current energy unit
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int L = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        try
        {
            if (L == 0)
            {
                Hilfe = 1;
                try
                {
                    for (int Spalte = 0; Spalte < Anzahl; Spalte++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                        {
                            DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value = meV[Spalte][i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            if (L == 1)
            {
                Hilfe = 2;
                try
                {
                    for (int Spalte = 0; Spalte < Anzahl; Spalte++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                        {
                            DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value = cm[Spalte][i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            if (L == 2)
            {
                Hilfe = 0;
                try
                {
                    for (int Spalte = 0; Spalte < Anzahl; Spalte++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                        {
                            DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value = eV[Spalte][i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest that you write your fix as an answer and mark is as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Accept these answer if you dont know `how to post your own answer?`.

Answer:

Problem fixed. The reason was the dgv.autosizemode , when i deactivate it before the conversions it runs.

```
for (int Spalte = 0; Spalte < Anzahl; Spalte++)
                        {
                            DGV[Spalte].AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
                            for (int i = 0; i < counter[Spalte]; i++)
                            {
                                DGV[Spalte][0, i].Value = meV[Spalte][i];
                            }
                            DGV[Spalte].AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
                        }
```